# Can I ask questions relating to workspace settings in Illustrator?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to achieve a specific layout for my illustrator (CS6 on OSX) workspace, but can't figure out how to do so. Is this appropriate SE site for this, or should I be asking on apple.stackexchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as answer as it didn't receive others yet.

I would say this is not a bad place, because you have a good chance of finding answers from experienced Illustrator users here. It looks more related to the software than to the OS, but that would depend on your question. It doesn't exactly fit the usual questions on the site, but in this case the designers' knowledge could be of help.